# apache 2.2.4 cannot load php5apache2_4.dll

Tags: php, apache

I wanted to install Apache and PHP without using xampp. Apache is working fine. When i type localhost in my browser it shows "It works!" but when i try to install PHP, i get always this error: 
"apache 2.2.4 cannot load php5apache2_4.dll into server: %1 is not a Win32-executable" (or something like this. Ive got a german version of the error)

I have windows 7 64bit. I re and installed multiple times but nothing changed. 
In my config i have this.

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php-5/php5apache2_4.dll"
```

Got anyone an idea?
Apache Version is 2.2.4 and Php5.6

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/303242/wamp-server-wont-run-with-php-5-3-4-but-will-with-php-5-2-11

Comment: I think you need to download that file from apachelounge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to have the same probleme so I switch to a Virtual Machine on Unix. My Probleme was here :

http://windows.php.net/download/

> Apache Please use the Apache builds provided by Apache Lounge. They
>   also provide VC11 builds of Apache for x86 and x64. We use their
>   binaries to build the Apache SAPIs.
>
> If you are using PHP with Apache 1 or Apache2 from apache.org (not
>   recommended) you need to use the older VC6 versions of PHP compiled
>   with the legacy Visual Studio 6 compiler. Do NOT use VC9+ versions of
>   PHP with the apache.org binaries.
>
> With Apache you have to use the Thread Safe (TS) versions of PHP.

I wanted to post this as a comment but it was to long.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My bad i didn't read the side info on the downloading page. Thank you! :)

Comment: You're welcome. That's why i switched to a virtual machine. My production server being on linux i used a vm under debian. The only tricky part for me was to have samba up and running to avoid using a ftp client just for testing. Once it done you'll find it quite useful with a server using exactly the amount of memory and cpu you need. No server on my dev machine.